# Bootstrap 3 Tooltips with Angular

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm attempting to use [Boostrap 3 tooltips](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) with Angular JS so that the tooltip displays the value of an object in the Angular scope. This works fine when the page loads, but when the value of the object in the scope is updated the tooltip still displays the original value.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="{{name}}">Hello {{name}}</span>
    <button type="button" ng-click="changeName()">Change</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Ian';
    $scope.changeName = function () {
        $scope.name = 'Alan';
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('span').tooltip();
});
```

There's an example demonstrating my code so far and the issue in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V5fkS/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Bootstrap Tooltip with AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666900/using-bootstrap-tooltip-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="{{name}}">Hello {{name}}</span>
```

Use:

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="{{name}}">Hello {{name}}</span>
```

Bootstrap Tooltip first checks **data-original-title**, so as long as you keep this value updated, you'll be fine. Check out this working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BKmbE/1/)

Comment: @stride It was your code that gave me a hint. I went to check what Bootstrap does with "data-original-title" after that :)

Comment: Thank you so much saved my time

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it is missing an apply for changed values, so angular knows nothing about that and does not update. I recommend angular ui bootstrap instead of raw bootstrap components for this reason.

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

This way there is no need for jquery which is a bonus in my book.

EDIT:
try this in change handler for a quick and dirty workaround:

```
$('span').tooltip('hide')
      .attr('data-original-title', $scope.name)
      .tooltip('fixTitle');
```

But as i said, check out angular version as this hack has several issues....

Answer (score 0):

For Latest Angular Versions Use: **[attr.data-original-title]="dynamicTooltipMsg"**

```
<button 
data-toggle="tooltip"     
[data-title]="dynamicTooltipMsg" 
[attr.data-original-title]="dynamicTooltipMsg">
    Testing
</button>
```