# Why does my Bootstrap popover not work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm trying to use the [Bootstrap popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers). So I copied the exact code from the example into my website, which unfortunately doesn't work. I pasted the full code below and created [a jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/L41g98qx/4/).

I tried putting it in a bootstrap container and in rows and columns, but nothing seems to work.

Does anybody how I can get that fiddle to work? All tips are welcome!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Gunaseelan you don't need to if you're including `bootstrap.min.js` like OP is.

Comment: I've updated your JSFiddle demo to include jQuery, as otherwise it was giving an error about jQuery being missing (despite being present in your snippet).

Comment: LOL, 6 answers in 10 minutes about the same thing: `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()`

Comment: `For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in, meaning you must initialize them yourself.` How come you get the document but you haven't seen it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap popover is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562366/bootstrap-popover-is-not-working)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You forgot this :
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#callout-popover-opt-in

> For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in, meaning you must initialize them yourself.
>
> One way to initialize all tooltips on a page would be to select them by their data-toggle attribute:

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

Comment: As this is the only answer which links to and quotes the source, +1 to you.

Answer (score 5):

```
<a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Dismissible popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?" id="example">Dismissible popover</a>
```

This method is required

```
$('#example').popover('show');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/L41g98qx/15/)**

Answer (score 3):

Should add the

```
$(function () {   
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover() 
});
```

working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vamsikrishnamannem/htnL6c8f/1/)

Answer (score 3):

For performance reason you should initilize popover by yourself :

```
<script>
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
</script>
```

[Reference](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers)

Be sure to add the jQuery library before bootstrap.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L41g98qx/5/)

Answer (score 3):

You were missing Function call into your fiddle and jquery library was also missing

I have added missing dependencies into your example

**check fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/L41g98qx/9/

here is a popover **function call**

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

Below text is copied from getbootstrap.com, here is what they want to say about the popover plugin

**Opt-in functionality**

> For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in, meaning you must initialize them yourself.
>
> One way to initialize all popovers on a page would be to select them
>   by their data-toggle attribute: Copy
>
> `$(function () {   $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover() })`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this `code` in body just above the `</body>` tag

```
$(function () {
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

Comment: Adding this to <head> is not working.  Started working when added in <body>.

Answer (score 0):

you can add an `id` or `class` attribute in the `button` and than call the popover method on that button. Here is the working fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/uqLor9ze/.

Here is the example code from [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uqLor9ze/)

```
 $('#pop').popover();
```